# How to avoid re-plug audio jack on startup?

Tags: 14.04, 18.04, sound, audio-jack

I have a problem similar to this other user:

[Have to re-plug speaker jack input to get sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743093/have-to-re-plug-speaker-jack-input-to-get-sound)

I've had previously Ubuntu 14.04 and changed to 18.04.
18.04 works better than 14.04, with one exception:

- My computer has an audio output with a jack, and it doesn't sound.  I have to re-plug it in order to listen something.  It's a little cumbersome to do so every time I restart the computer, because the main use is to hear musc and see videos.  It is clearly a software problem.

Apart from installing the old Ubuntu 14.04, is there any other solution?

My audio chipset is Conexant CX20751/2 and it is an Asus notebook.

I've tried to use the hdajackrepack, by installing the alsa-tools, alsa-tools-gui packages but unsuccessful.  Maybe is that I don't know how to tweak it.

Related questions:

- [hdajackretask in alsa-tools-gui breaks PulseAudio conf of on-board audio dev in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998707/hdajackretask-in-alsa-tools-gui-breaks-pulseaudio-conf-of-on-board-audio-dev-in)

Answer (score 0):

The [answer to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998707/hdajackretask-in-alsa-tools-gui-breaks-pulseaudio-conf-of-on-board-audio-dev-in) has provided me the clue.  I've run `hdajackrepack` utility first as root and it seems to have created files with wrong permissions, instead of using `sudo hdajackrepack`.

Instead of uninstalling PulseAudio and Alsa, I've reinstalled the whole operating system as it is simpler.  As I have separated / and /home partitions, I keep all my settings and personal data after a reinstallation.

Then I've run `sudo hdajackrepack` and have installed the retasking of the headphone output to line (front).

Restarted the system and now I can hear the sound through the loudspeakers. :-)